# Loop through plsql code for a number of tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

A master table is to be updated daily with the input data from two sources in two tables.  The plsql code for processing the two tables are practically identical except for the table names.  We have to separately log possible errors about the data in the input tables therefore have to run the code once each for the two input tables.

The attempted solution is by putting the table names in a variable, and cycle through the code twice:

```
declare
   input_table varchar2(20);
begin
   for i in (select column_value as var from table(sys.ODCIvarchar2List('MIDGETS', 'GIANTS'))) loop
      if i.var = 'MIDGETS' then
         input_table := 'midget_table';
      elsif i.var = 'GIANTS' then
         input_table := 'giant_table';
      end if;

      for rec in (select col1, col2 from input_table) loop

         <the processing code>

      end loop;
end;
/
```

The problem is that plsql does not seem to be aware that input_table is a variable.  It "thinks" that *input_table* is literally the name of the table, and returns the (ORA-00942: table or view does not exist) error.

Since this is dynamic code, the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE was then tried:

```
declare
   input_table varchar2(20);
begin
   for ... 'MIDGETS', 'GIANTS' ... loop
      input_table := ...
      ...
   end loop;

   for rec in ( EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select col1, col2 from ' || input_table ) loop
      <processing>
   end loop;
end;
/
```

But EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is not allowed either in this context.

Is there a way at all?  Or is making two copies of the .sql file, one for MIDGETS and one for GIANTS, the only way out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic query as below

```
declare
   type crs_type is ref cursor;
   c crs_type;
   v_query     varchar2(2000);
   input_table varchar2(20);
   v_col1      midgets.col1%type; -- assuming identical data types for common named columns
   v_col2      midgets.col2%type;
begin
   for ... 'MIDGETS', 'GIANTS' ... loop
      input_table := ...
      ...
   end loop;


   v_query := 'select col1, col2 from ' || input_table;
   open c for v_query;
   loop
    fetch c into v_col1, v_col2;
    exit when c%notfound;
      <processing>
   end loop;
   close c;
end;
```

Comment: Great!  That solved my problem.  Thanks!  To clarify for anyone this could be of reference value, in solving my problem, the cursor loop should have been embedded in the "for ... 'MIDGETS', 'GIANTS' loop".  That was my mistake in the second code excerpt of my original posting. Sorry for that.